# $ax^2 + b$ and infinitely many primes: Does existence proof exist?

Tags: number-theory

The question is on a subset of [Bunyakovsky's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky%5fconjecture) on an infinite number of primes existing in integer polynomials of degree higher than $1$. The conjecture itself is open.

I have not been able to find if even an existence proof exists. That is has it at least been proven, even just for degree $2$, that such a polynomial exists even if we cannot produce one?

Comment: This conjecture is open for all polynomials of degree greater than one, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it has not been proved that there exists a quadratic polynomial in one variable that represents infinitely many primes.